# IF Statement Not Returning Expected Result

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am running into an issue in AMPscript where the following IF statement is returning my variable @shippingVendor as nothing when I call it. (Tracking Number is from data extension)

Assuming @trackingNumber = 23456

```
%%[
var @shippingVendor

IF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 1) == "2" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/"
  ELSEIF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 2) == "T1" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mainfreight.com/en-nz/tracking?trackingnumber="
  ELSEIF Substring(@trackingNumber, 1, 3) == "TP1" THEN
   SET @shippingVendor = "https://www.mytoll.com/?"
ENDIF
]%%
```

I would expect %%=v(@shippingVendor)=%% to return "https://www.nzpost.co.nz/tools/tracking/item/" - however instead it returns nothing...can I please check if I am doing anything wrong?

Fairly new to AMPscript so would love your help on this - thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need to check if you get the correct value for `@trackingNumber` since when I put `SET @trackingNumber = 23456` into the block code, I can get expected result like you mentioned

Comment: Can you show how you set @trackingNumber?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74799918/812377